# Convert String "2019-03-15 09:25:00" to millisecond in react-native

Tags: react-native

I need to convert this string format to millisecond.

I tried to user [Moment](https://medium.com/quick-code/using-moment-js-in-react-native-d1b6ebe226d4) to get millisecond

```
moment('2019-03-15 09:25:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').milliseconds()
```

but it shows me 0 value.

All help is appreciated... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [moment.js get current time in milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980722/moment-js-get-current-time-in-milliseconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

valueOf will used to get milliseconds.

```
m = moment('2019-03-15 09:25:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log(m.valueOf());
```